# How can get the current path in PHP

Tags: php

How can I return the path of the current page including whats after ?

So for example I am this link

```
localhost/site1/index.php?view=10&user=5
```

I want to return this value `"index.php?view=10&user=5"`

How can I do that using PHP?

I thought `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` do this but `SCRIPT_NAME` is returing index.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Surely the "path" of the page includes the site1/

Comment: Just `var_dump($_SERVER)` and pick the one you like.

Comment: Little hint for future:) `print_r($_SERVER)` will show you some interesting things ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`

and

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

request uri will give you full uri, you can manipulate it to get the last path

as @Mathieu Imbert said, get curious.  Inspect everything `$_SERVER` gives you either by `var_dump` or by reading documentation i linked to in a comment

Comment: this is it $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']  Thank you :)